# Path defined in controller and action is getting ignored, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, path, render

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

I should be able to define the path from a different controller as I have done in my create action in my micropostscontroller:

```
def create
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
      if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
        redirect_to profile_path
      else
        render 'static_pages/profile'
      end
    end
```

When I unsuccessfully create a post, however (leave it blank or make it too long), the page '/microposts' is rendered, the nonexistent home page of the controller. When I successfully create a micropost I am redirected to the profile path '/profile', and when I've changed `render 'static_pages/profile'` to `redirect_to profile_path` the redirect works. Why is the browser ignoring the render request and going to the microposts controller home?

Additionally, the rendered microposts page gives a NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError in Microposts#create

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>

app/views/static_pages/profile.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_static_pages_profile_html_erb___1610169404003779010_70327969935820'
app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

The profile renders fine on its own when when redirected to, as @user is defined in profile action in the static_pages controller. `@user = User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your create method is attempting to render 'app/views/static_pages/profile.html.erb', but you haven't given it a @user to render. If you revise your code this way it should work:

```
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
  if @micropost.save
    flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
    redirect_to profile_path
  else
    @user = current_user # Add this line!
    render 'static_pages/profile'
  end
end
```

Note that the path of the `microposts#create` method is `/microposts`, so that will still show in your address bar unless you use `redirect_to` instead of `render`.

Comment: Why not just `@user = current_user`?

Comment: Edited to reflect your suggestion! I was just borrowing the snippet he mentioned he used in his static_pages controller.

Comment: For some reason I'm still having trouble getting error messages to show, which I wish I thought I needed to render, but it seems rendering isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood what `render` does. It just changes which template is rendered. It does not cause any code from the controller related to the template (if there is one) to be executed.

The stack trace shows that it is rendering the file you requested, although it would seem that it expects `@user` to be defined, which you don't seem to be doing in your create action. Set `@user` to `current_user` and you should be fine.

Redirecting is probably a better choice though - if the user refreshes the page it may resubmit the form data, whereas with the redirect that won't happen.