# Action won't render on validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a fairly standard controller with a create method and some validations.

```
def create
  @type = Type.new(params[:type])    
  respond_to do |format|
    if @type.save
      format.html { redirect_to types_path, notice: 'Type was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @type, status: :created, location: @type }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @type.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when a validation fails, I get the error`Missing template ontology/types/create`, as if the `render action: "new"` weren't there. If I replace it with a `redirect_to` then it works as expected, but then it seems I can't pass the form errors along.

I know that there is a @type instance (with @type.errors) from the original call of new, and throwing it just before the render call confirms this.

The same thing is happening when a validation fails on update It seems like the render call is just being ignored!

NOTE: my routing structure is a little unconventional, but I see not reason why this should be related.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar: [Path defined in controller and action is getting ignored, Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127664/path-defined-in-controller-and-action-is-getting-ignored-ruby-on-rails)

Based on the answer to that question, I'm guessing that something is missing that is needed for rendering the `new` view, and as a result rails is just skipping the `render` call altogether and rendering `create`.

Can you show the `new` controller action and view?